# How to update a field which can appear in different locations in document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("12345678"),
  "name": "object name",
  "descriptions": "object description",
  "questions": {
    "mandatory": [
      {
        "name": "question name",
        "mandatory": true,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "option1 value"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "optional": [
      {
        "name": "question name",
        "mandatory": false,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "option4 value"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my collection I want to update all documents that have an item with specific id. The problem is that an `item` that I want to update, can appear under either `mandatory` or under `optional`. Right now, I use separate query to update items under optional:

```
itemCollection.update(
    {
    'questions.optional':{$exists:true}
    },
    {
        $set:{"questions.optional.$[].items.$[itemField].name":item.name}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters:
        [
            {"itemField.id": itemId}
        ],
        $multi:true
    }, (error) => {
        if(!error){
           // do something if no error
        }
    }
)
```

Then I use the same query (with the required changes) to update items under mandatory.
Is there a way I can combine those two queries into one, such that if the document has the item with the desired id, it will be updated, regardless if it's under mandatory or under optional?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to update both `optional` and `mandatory` arrays?

Comment: No, not both, the item will be only under one of them. So for each document I need to update only one of them.

Comment: you can use `$or` with the `$exists` and when setting updates add both arrays. If `upsert: false` it will update only existing array.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov thanks. Can you please show a small example, I never used `upsert`, so I'm not sure how to use it with both arrays.

Comment: Just add after `multi: true` comma and `upsert: false`. I'm typing from the mobile phone, sorry for not showing an example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the item will be present in only one of the array, the following query can do the trick:

```
db.collection.update({},
    {
        $set:{
            "questions.mandatory.$[].items.$[filter].name": "Updated Name",
            "questions.optional.$[].items.$[filter].name": "Updated Name"
        }
    },
    {
        "arrayFilters":[
            {
                "filter.id":4
            }
        ]
    }
)
```